# Pre-hook git message validation fails using regex on bash fails

Tags: regex, bash, githooks

I have to validate the structure of a commit message to be consistent with the following structure:

```
<type>(optional description): <subject>

<BLANK LINE>

<optional body>

<BLANK LINE>

<footer>
```

Type, subject and footer are required.

And 'footer' (mandatory) has a structure like:

```
Closes #S2169505 (https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/?detail=/userstory/123456)
```

And additionally can have BREAKING CHANGES(optional) like:

```
BREAKING CHANGE: Something is breaking thanks to this commit.
```

Examples:

Valid commit message

```
feat: Implement retry logic for outbound requests

If outbound requests fail with a transient exception, they will be automatically
retried for a configured number of times. If the exception is not transient, the
request is not retried and the error is returned to the controller.

This should ensure that temporary failures will more likely return success. 

Closes #S2169505 (https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/?detail=/userstory/123456)
BREAKING CHANGE: Something is breaking thanks to this commit.
```

Another valid commit message:

```
test(some optional thing): Implement retry logic for outbound requests
Closes #S2169505 (https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/?detail=/userstory/123456)
BREAKING CHANGE: Something is breaking thanks to this commit.
```

Invalid commit messages:

```
feat: Implement retry logic for outbound requests

If outbound requests fail with a transient exception, they will be automatically
retried for a configured number of times. If the exception is not transient, the
request is not retried and the error is returned to the controller.

This should ensure that temporary failures will more likely return success. 

Closes #S2169505 (https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/?detail=/userstory/123456)
THIS TEXT SHOULD NOT BE HERE
```

Another invalid commit message(it has no footer):

```
feat: Implement retry logic for outbound requests
```

I created a #bash script to validate the message:

```
#!/bin/sh

msg="" #THE MENTIONED COMMIT MESSAGE
regExp='^(test|feat)(\(.+\))?:(.+)((.|\n)*)?(Closes #.+ \(.+\))([\n]*BREAKING CHANGE:.+)?$'

if [[ $msg =~ $regExp ]];
then
    echo "cool"
else
    echo "NOT cool"
fi

exit 1
```

my regex contains the following structure:

`^` Init of the message

`(test|feat)` 'type'

`(\(.+\))?` optional message in parenthesis

`:` colon separator between 'type' and 'subject'

`(.+)` subject

`((.|\n)*)?` optional 'body'

`(Closes #.+ \(.+\))` mandatory footer

`([\n]*BREAKING CHANGE:.+)?` optional extra footer

`$` End of the message

Unfortunately my script is not working(printing `NOT cool`).
If I omit the end of the message symbol on the regex (`$`) the script works (prints 'cool') but then it returns also success for the 3rd example which is invalid since after the `Closes` footer cannot exist more content (unless is a breaking change).

**Additionally**: I'm testing this running the script on the console, is there any way to print what the regex is selecting(and not selecting) from the provided message?

Comment: if you get a match (script generates 'cool') you can run `typeset -p BASH_REMATCH` (or `declare -p BASH_REMATCH`) to see how `bash` matched the regex

Answer (score 1):

I found out the solution; Bash/shell uses 'ERE' and instead of using character like ' ' or '\n' I replaced them by `[:blank:]` `[:space:]` and others, like specified [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX-Extended_Regular_Expressions)

Special thanks to @markp-fuso, sir, your response indicating how to check the matched regex solved all my issues (I was able to "debug" my regex)

My final regex is:

```
regExp='^(build|ci|docs|feat|fix|perf|refactor|style|test)(\(.+\))?:[[:blank:]]([[:alnum:][:blank:][:punct:]]+)[[:space:]]+([[:space:][:punct:][:alnum:]]*)(Closes[[:blank:]]#[[:alnum:]]+[[:blank:]]\([[:alnum:][:punct:]]+)[[:space:]]?(BREAKING[[:blank:]]CHANGE:[[:blank:]][[:blank:][:alnum:][:punct:]]+)?$'
```